# How to escape double and single quote from JS string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm assigning the value of JS `string` variable from server side code.

Like this

```
var fbShareTitle = "@(ViewBag.LeadTitle as string)";
```

`ViewBag` return string value is

```
A "Fantastic" Lead With 'Qoute'
```

Now It is giving error in console

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

I have tried this

```
var fbShareTitle = ("@(ViewBag.LeadTitle)").replace(/"/g, '\\"');
```

But now I'm getting this error.

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

As This string will be shared on fb, So i can't modify string, like replace all `"` with `'` e.t.c.

Comment: Please post your entire code.

Comment: @AMACB since this question is asked so many times there is really no need to post actual code... Something basic search like https://www.bing.com/search?q=C%23+razor+javascript+quotes could have revealed answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code doesn't work is that Razor will generate the following:

```
var fbShareTitle = "A "Fantastic" Lead With 'Qoute'";
```

which is invalid JavaScript. You can't simply fix it by `replace`, since it's not the problem that your string is bad, it's that your *code* can't parse - `replace` never gets to execute. You need to fix it on serverside, where you generate the JavaScript in question, by modifying your Razor code:

```
var fbShareTitle = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.LeadTitle as string));
```

`Json` will take care of quotes and proper escaping; `Raw` will make sure you don't get your `<` and `>` replaced. Extra benefit from `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(...))` mantra: you can use it to inject any kind of data that can be encoded in JSON, not only strings.

Comment: Hello, what is the correct namespace of ``Json``?

Comment: @Sasinosoft I believe it's [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.helpers.json?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2), but I haven't worked with .NET in a long time :)